# Specifying the maven repository URL for getting the dependencies resolved?

Tags: maven, hadoop, repository

I am trying to understand how maven downloads the binaries from the repositories.

For example, I have the following dependency for my project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
    <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Now, these binaries are present in http://mvnrepository.com/.

In pom.xml, we have `<repositories>` tag where we specify the repository URL from where maven can download the files, template:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>mvnrepository_id</id>
        <name>mvnrepository.com</name>
        <url></url>
    </repository>
```

Now, my doubt is, what should be the value of the `<url>`; does it need to be the `base url` , like http://mvnrepository.com/ or the complete URL --> http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.hadoop/hadoop-hdfs

To me it appears that is should be the base url else for each dependency we have to put the complete URL.

Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: mvnrepository.com is not a Maven repository nor Maven Central...which means you can't use it to consume artifacts...Why not using [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search|ga|1|g%3A%22org.apache.hadoop%22%20a%3A%22hadoop-hdfs%22) which contains the artifacts.

Comment: Thanks so much, i referred to this link from one of the SO questions. But the question is same, we need to provide the base of the repository?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you want to fetch artifacts from a repository different from the default Central Maven repository, you need not add the `<repositories>` section to your `pom.xml`. Read about Maven Repositories [here](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories) and [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html).

And the `url` for default Central Maven repository is http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.

**PS:** The URLs you have posted are the ones for the Website.

Comment: Thanks so much for the info; so we have to provide the "base url" and then maven will download based on the artifacts of the dependency, is this correct?

Comment: The `groupId` and `artifactId` are the required values. `mvn` will fetch the artifacts from the central repo, you need not provide the url unless you want to change the default repo.